# Visualize a linestring and point from a PostGIS database in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, openstreetmap, point, linestring

I ran a query in PostGIS table using a table of roads/linestrings in Hawaii and another table with 400,000 (longitude,latitude) points in Hawaii.  The output table is meant to provide nearest road in Hawaii for each of the 400,000 (longitude,latitude) points.  The output table has the following columns.

Point ID   |  Line ID  |  Distance   |   Point   |   Line   |    Highway_Tag

For each row, the line column is closest road (type LineString) to the point (type point geometry).
How can I validate that this is really the case in QGIS?
My PostGIS database is connected to QGIS.
I'd like to select several rows at random and check if the point is somewhere on the line.

Comment: Vertices in PostGIS aren't {lat,lon}, they're {lon,lat}.

Comment: In QGIS you could use the distance matrix tool (vector > analysis tools > distance matrix) setting to one the number of nearest points. Afterwards, you could validate the results in this new layer "by hand" or with a random selection (vector > research tools > random selection) of its features.